# How to find available JSON requests from URL

Tags: json, indexing

I'm trying to do a search on a website and I'm trying to discover the available options when making the GET call.  This is the error:

```
{
      "apiVersion":"v1",
      "meta":{
              "pluginVersion":"v3.2.1",
               "isExtruded":true
              },
      "error":{
            "code":"Bad Request",
            "status":400,
            "diagnosticMessage":"invalid barcode type"
              }
}
```

I know 2 valid barcode types, but I'm trying to figure out all available valid types.  Is there a request one can make that lists possible valid values for a variable?  Further, is there a way to list the available variables a site has for requests?  I'm thinking along the lines of an index.

Comment: The API probably does come with some kind of documentation showing the available endpoints... Maybe you could post a few more details on which URL you are querying etc..?

Comment: You can't guess the structure of request, you should find it in the documentation of this web service.

Comment: thanks guys.  That's what I was afraid of.  There is no documentation of the service as far as I can tell.